# What's the purpose of Health.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

In order to determine the site's scope in specific instances, we need to have a unified, general, but short purpose for the site.

For example, the purpose of StackOverflow is a "site for professional and enthusiast programmers ...  to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming".

Who is this site for and what is our purpose here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sort of partial to [the original description](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health) that launched this site:

> Health SE is a Q&A site for medical specialists, students, dietitians and anyone with health-related questions.

Comment: So if I am not a medical specialist, whatever that is, a student, or a dietitian, then I am not welcome if I only want to answer questions? I think trying to list who the site is for is a bad idea.

Comment: "...and anyone with health-related questions."

Comment: We want to welcome people without questions, but want to answer.

Comment: I feel like this doesn't give quite enough of a focus because "health-related" can be interpreted in many different ways. I'd like it to be a little more clear personally

Comment: The quoted description is tautological. It basically says "*Health SE is for health-related questions*" (because of the **anyone**). I wouldn't try to give a definition now, just answer the many "is ... on-topic" questions that people are asking on the meta. I think it's a good way to form a consensus.

Comment: I think that this description is insufficient, as it somewhat fails to define the scope of questions that could be asked. In my mind, a good definition should leave it clear when a "health-related" question might fall into another site's umbrella.