# Should we use medical terms or layman's terms as tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

In this [discussion about [renal-calculi] and [kidney-stones]](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/60/113), the question has come up if we should use specialized medical terms or generic layman's terms for tagging.

What do you think?

Comment: See also: [Do we have a general system of class of drugs that a layman can understand?](http://health.stackexchange.com/q/1014/99)

Comment: I look forward to the further discussion of this as it applies to human genitalia.  Debating which synonyms to use will perhaps lead to the most humorous meta discussion ever.  I nominate "tallywacker" for the men and "vajayjay" for the ladies.

Answer (score 11):

While the [focus of Health SE is still being discussed](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/39/113), the [original site description](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health) so far has been:

> Health SE is a Q&A site for medical specialists, students, dietitians and anyone with health-related questions.

Medical specialists, students and dietitians should understand medical terms, and they will also use these terms while (re)searching. However, most people with health-related questions who are not part of any of the former groups will probably have no idea what *renal calculi* are.

This is why I suggest the following approach:

> Use generic layman's terms for tagging, and add technical medical terms
>   as tag synonyms.

For an example, have a look at [Kevin's answer](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/64/113) (that actually inspired this answer).

Answer (score 6):

I would be in favor of using both, as synonyms.

The rationale behind this is that depending on who you are as a user, you may be interested in one or the other.

(Just an) example: in first aid, a layman may be interested in searching or to tag a question with "nose bleed". A CFR, an EMT, etc, would be prone to use "epistaxis" instead, like a kind of conditioned reflex.

Comment: Depends on context. I would be more apt to say nosebleed when reporting in to medical control, but write epistaxis on the run sheet.